# Populating a bash array (of items containing spaces) from jq

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I decided to write a little bash parser script I kinda succ in bash and jq.
So I using curl to get json from reddit and jq to extract value from it, I want get titles as list of sentences what is the best way to get it?

**Code example**

```
#getting title
titles=($(echo "${json}" | jq '.data.children[].data.title'))
echo "full list is"
echo ${titles[@]}
echo

#copyed by hand from previos output^ 
hand_titles=("Developers Should Celebrate Software Development Being Hard" "Lies we tell ourselves to keep using Golang")

echo "I want to call var like this and get this output:"
echo ${hand_titles[0]}
echo
echo "But instead I get this: "
echo ${titles[0]}
```

**Console output**

```
full list is
"Developers Should Celebrate Software Development Being Hard" "Lies we tell ourselves to keep using Golang"

I want to call var like this and get this output:
Developers Should Celebrate Software Development Being Hard

But instead I get this:
"Developers
```

I want to use a for loop to Iterate trough list in parallel and use ${titles[i]} and for this I need output a sentence "Developers Should Celebrate Software Development Being Hard" not a damn word

Maybe I suppose record it to file or something then read it to use it properly I dunno

Comment: `array=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29).

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: ...and to understand the root cause of the problem, see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). The very short explanation of the problem is that literal and syntactic quotes are _not the same thing_ and don't substitute for each other; quotes that are _part of your data_ don't act like quotes that are part of your code, and _shouldn't_ -- if they did, it would be impossible to write correct/safe code in shell languages that handled untrusted data.

Comment: BTW, `echo ${titles[@]}` acts **exactly** like `echo ${titles[*]}`; it has no pretense at all of keeping the boundaries between your individual elements intact. _Always_ quote your expansions -- and, when you want to know the boundaries, don't use `echo` at all; `printf '<%s> ' "${titles[@]}"; echo` tells you where each individual title starts and stops so you can see if your array is correct. (Then again, so does `declare -p titles`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your titles can't contain literal newlines (well, literal after decoding, `\n` within JSON strings), the easy way to do this is:

```
readarray -t titles < <(jq -r '.data.children[].data.title' <<<"$json")
echo "full list is"
printf ' - %s\n' "${titles[@]}"
echo "First title is ${titles[0]}"
```

`readarray` (also called `mapfile`) is a bash 4.0 feature that reads each line of input into a separate array element; using `jq -r` makes jq's output line-oriented without extra JSON quoting/escaping.

---

If they *can* contain newlines, it gets a little trickier:

```
readarray -d '' titles < <(
  jq -j '.data.children[].data.title | (., "\u0000")' <<<"$json"
)
echo "full list is"
printf ' - %s\n' "${titles[@]}"
echo "First title is ${titles[0]}"
```

`-d ''` tells readarray to expect items to be NUL-terminated; `-j` tells jq to do raw output but *not* append a newline automatically after each item; `(., "\u0000")` manually adds those NUL terminators. (If you're dealing with data that's going to be interpreted on the other side of a privilege boundary from that data's source, think about stripping any NULs inside the JSON before adding new/extra ones as separators; I've been known to put something like `sub("\u0000"; "<NUL>")` inside my pipelines).

---

In both the examples above, note how above we're printing each array element on its own line to demonstrate that the items were held together correctly.

Comment: (Converted to community-wiki since the question is a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

You could make jq generate the body of a `declare` statement:

```bash
$ unset titles
$ declare -a titles="($(jq -r '.data.children[].data.title | @sh' <<< "$json"))"
```

Then, you can use the resulting Bash array:

```bash
$ echo "${titles[0]}"
Developers Should Celebrate Software Development Being Hard
```

Comment: This _works_, and is safe because you're using `@sh` to generate eval-safe escaping, but insofar as you're depending on `declare` parsing data as code, it's not something I'd defend as good practice (as soon as someone uses it in a context that doesn't have any equivalent to that `@sh`, we've got shell injection vulnerabilities).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. Unless there is a safe, dedicated interface for this (or any kind of) job, every workaround has its own caveats.